# RecyclerView doesn't scroll

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am new to android development and I was trying to make a log using **RecyclerView** and **CardView**. But the problem that I am facing is that the **RecyclerView** won't scroll. I did a little research on this issue, but yet couldn't find a way to solve the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code for my RecyclerView,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vishistvarugeese.ongc_app.AdminActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/headernav"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Recent Logins"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/admin_nav_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:menu="@menu/admin_menu">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code for my CardView is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLoginTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recentLoginCpf"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLoginName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLoginCpf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recentLoginName"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Reg Number"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLoginType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recentLoginCpf"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/recentLoginCpf"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recentLoginTime"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Type"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

The java code for RecyclerView,

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private List<ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        //Recycler View
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin listItem = new ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin(
                    "9:30",
                    "Name",
                    "808821",
                    "Admin"
            );
            listItems.add(listItem);
       }
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(listItems,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

The code for the adapter,

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin> listitems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listitems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem_RecyclerView_Admin listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.recentLoginName.setText(listItem.getRecentLoginName());
        holder.recentLoginTime.setText(listItem.getRecentLoginTime());
        holder.recentLoginCpf.setText(listItem.getRecentLoginCpf());
        holder.recentLoginType.setText(listItem.getRecentLoginType());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView recentLoginName;
        private TextView recentLoginTime;
        private TextView recentLoginCpf;
        private TextView recentLoginType;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recentLoginName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recentLoginName);
            recentLoginTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recentLoginTime);
            recentLoginCpf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recentLoginCpf);
            recentLoginType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recentLoginType);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I wanted the **Date and Recent Logins header** to be static and not scroll. I tried to do this by putting them inside a **Linear Layout**. But I don't think this is the right way to do it. [image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/headernav"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Recent Logins"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: add the java code for recyclerview and also adapter class

Comment: I have added the java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the content of your layout within `DrawerLayout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/headernav"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recentLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Recent Logins"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

        </ FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/admin_nav_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:menu="@menu/admin_menu">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved the problem. But can you please tell me what was wrong and how putting everything inside the `DrawerLayout` solved it?

Comment: You would love this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getApplication(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

set linearlayoutManager Vertical

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow, when providing answers code is good but unexplained code if of now use this site is not a do it for you it's a show you the correct way and explain why it's correct so people understand what they got wrong, this also help people learn copy and paste you don't learn understanding where you went wrong and how to fix helps people to learn from there mistakes please provide an explination of why this code will work.